# Nautilus hides the window when launched

Tags: unity, compiz, nautilus

Okay. So I had no problems with Nautilus but then....BAM! It hides almost quarter of the window when launched. Managed to fix it by turning off wobbly windows. Don't understand. It worked perfectly just a while back. It seems to go back to maximized when I drag a little bit of the black area but it kinda sucks doing it every time.

Any idea on how to fix this?!

[image: http://i47.tinypic.com/1ihkpv.png]

Comment: Try presssing CTRL+ALT+5 (in the numpad) and then restart nautilus

Comment: On Laptop. No numpad. Any alternatives?

Comment: Only on nautilus? Looks loke you missing the panel too

Comment: Seems you've been playing around with Compiz Config settings program?  Have you looked at the Window Management settings, such as "Placed windows", etc?

Comment: The panel is there. I have to hover the mouse over to let it show.

Tried messing with Placed Windows. No luck :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to happen when Wobbly Windows **and** Window Decoration are enabled at the same time... If you disable any of the two options the problem disappear. And in the case that the two are enabled at the same time the nautilus windows show the strange behavior randomly (at least in my case)...

What I've done is disable Window Decoration only for Nautilus.

Go to CompizConfig/Effects/Window Decoration/Decoration Windows and replace **any** by **(any) & !(class=Nautilus)**

The downside of that is that it remove the top bar on the nautilus window but you can still move it by grabbing the black space around the address bar...

Comment: After system updates today I needed to remove this modification in Compiz because the problem seems to be solved !